# Redis: is there a way to MASTEROF rather than SLAVEOF?

Tags: redis

Is it possible for a Redis master instance to initiate a connection for replication to a slave?

What i need is for the master to MASTEROF to the slave instead of a SLAVEOF.

Use case: Redis Master on private network ip address and I want to create a replica on a server on an externally/publicly accessible ip address. Useful when slaves cannot see the master which is on a private 192.168.x.x ip address.

Answer (score 0):

I'm [afraid not](http://redis.io/topics/replication).  Since Redis allows replication from a single master to many slaves, the command you're looking for wouldn't make a lot of sense.

For your situation, you might consider one of several options:

1. Change your network setup so that the Redis master is publicly visible.
2. Add a slave which has a public address, but which is still within your network (i.e., so it can still see the master).  Then, set up your public slave to replicate from that.
3. [Use SSH](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1) to create a tunnel from your slave to your master and forward the appropriate ports along (i.e., use the -L and -N options).  By adding the public key from your slave machine to your master machine's `~/.ssh/authenticated_keys` file, you won't have to use a password to log in.